# How to handle exceptions a list of deferred in Kotlin to get successful elements?

Tags: kotlin, kotlin-coroutines

I have something like

```
listOf(
    getItem1Async(),
    getItem2Async(), //error
    getItem3Async()
).awaitAl
```

any of the functions could get an exception but because they return a deferred the exception is not handled until the await() call. I want for example if getItem2Async fails that my list creation doesn't fail but to get a default value or a null one and keep the successful calls.

I was looking into the documentation and couldn't figure out how to use the await on a list of deferred to return the items with no exception. I found something about a CoroutineExceptionHandler but cannot manage to return a null or default value, and also I read about a Supervisor job but I'm not sure if its the correct tool or if I sould use other one.

Comment: You’ll need to stick them in their own coroutine scope with a custom error handler.

Answer (score 4):

First, we need to use [supervisorScope()](https://kotlin.github.io/kotlinx.coroutines/kotlinx-coroutines-core/kotlinx.coroutines/supervisor-scope.html), so crashed child coroutines won't affect other coroutines. Then we can use [Deferred.getCompleted()](https://kotlin.github.io/kotlinx.coroutines/kotlinx-coroutines-core/kotlinx.coroutines/-deferred/get-completed.html), [Deferred.getCompletionExceptionOrNull()](https://kotlin.github.io/kotlinx.coroutines/kotlinx-coroutines-core/kotlinx.coroutines/-deferred/get-completion-exception-or-null.html) or similar functions to acquire a result:

```kotlin
suspend fun main() {
    supervisorScope {
        listOf(
            async { "hello" },
            async { check(false) },
            async { "world" },
        )
    }.map { it.getCompletedOrNull() }
        .forEach(::println)
}

@OptIn(ExperimentalCoroutinesApi::class)
fun <T> Deferred<T>.getCompletedOrNull() = if (isCancelled) null else getCompleted()
```

Comment: `getCompleted()` rethrows any exception other than CancellationException, so maybe it should be wrapped: `runCatching { getCompleted() }.getOrNull()`.

Comment: Hmm... doesn't `isCancelled == false` imply that coroutine succeeded? Name `isCancelled` is a little misleading, because failures in coroutines are considered cancellations. Also, if that would be the case then I believe above code should throw at `map()`, but it actually returns null for the second item.

Comment: You're right about the behavior. I was under the mistaken belief that "cancelled" and "completed" were mutually exclusive opposites, and that cancelled is exclusively for CancellationExceptions.

Comment: Honestly, API of `Job`/`Deferred` feels unnatural to me. There is no simple `isSucceeded`, but instead we need to check `isCompleted` and `isCancelled`. There is no `getCompletedOrNull()`, but there is `getCompletionExceptionOrNull()`. This is confusing. @Tenfour04